# How to use custom pattern for my Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

i write this component for input ,when i use input on Change work correctly but if i use this component not work correct, error show correctly but type number in input

-----Component textBox-------

```
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className={"d-block"} htmlFor={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}</label>
            <input type={this.props.type}
                   name={this.props.id}
                   onClick={this.props.clicked}
                   onChange={this.props.onChange}
                   placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                   className={"form-control"}
                   id={this.props.id}
                  />
            <span className="text-danger" aria-live="polite">{this.props.error}</span>
        </div>
```

-------Handle onChange-------

```
 handleChangezipCode=(e) =>{
        if (e.target.value.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$") != null) {
            this.setState({
                zipCode: e.target.value,
                zipCodeError: "correct"
            })

        } else {
            this.setState({
                zipCodeError: "error"
            })
        }
    }
```

-----------form ------------

```
            <TextBox
                type="text"
                label="zipCode"
                placeholder="zipCode"
                id="zipCode"
                ref="zipCode"
                error={this.state.zipCodeError}
                value={this.state.zipCode}
                onChange={this.handleChangezipCode}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not controlling the input value just validating it outside of textbox component, you are not able to control what you enter inside the input with type as `text`. Passing a value attribute to `input` which is assigned from props will work

```
   <div className="form-group">
        <label className={"d-block"} htmlFor={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}</label>
        <input type={this.props.type}
               name={this.props.id}
               onClick={this.props.clicked}
               onChange={this.props.onChange}
               placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
               className={"form-control"}
               value={this.props.value || undefined}
               id={this.props.id}
              />
        <span className="text-danger" aria-live="polite">{this.props.error}</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are passing `value={this.state.zipCode}` as a prop to `TextBox` component right?